# Remotely execute programs via Amazon Alexa

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, keylogger

I am currently in the process of developing a project where I use a python keylogger I have made. But I want to execute the keylogger via a voice command to Alexa. Is this possible at the moment to do in an Alexa skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is supported out of the box without AWS services, but on a quick search (yes, this is from a quick internet search because I liked the idea you have) Amazon provides this service via Lambda function. AWS Lambda function is a service that is fired when needed and you are charged only for the time of execution of your code.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html